# ensureIndex is undefined on the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using version 
$ mongod --version
db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Jan 29 23:53:30 git version: nogitversion

Trying to create a uniqueIndex on the "mykey".

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/mydb';

mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
    db.collection('mydocs', function(er, collection) {
    db.mydocs.ensureIndex({"mykey":1}, {unique: true});
        collection.insert({'mykey': 'myvalue'}, {safe: true}, function(er,rs) {
    });

    });
});
```

node app
 throws follwing error
**TypeError: Cannot call method 'ensureIndex' of undefined**

Comment: maybe `db.collection('mydocs').ensureIndex();`?

Comment: With that node gives following error Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback
    at Db.ensureIndex

Comment: If you're usnig `mongoNative` maybe this helps: https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/examples/queries.js#L102

Comment: Or here https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/examples/index.js#L37

Comment: You should also consider upgrading from MongoDB 2.0.4 to the latest production release (currently 2.4.9), or at a minimum the latest 2.0.x release.  MongoDB 2.0.4 was released almost 2 years ago (March 2012) and there have been significant improvements in stability, performance, and features since then.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 and the older version is the default one in it.

Answer (score -1):

The below code works

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/mydb';

mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
    db.collection("mydocs", function(er, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex({mykey: 1}, {unique: true}, function() {});
        collection.insert({mykey: 'myvalue'}, {safe: true}, function(er,rs) {
    });

    });
});
```